# Civi Event Participant Status ID

Tags: civievent, import

I'm trying to create a simple spreadsheet to import event participants, and need to add the Participant Status codes to import.

Is there a list anywhere or which codes correspond to which statuses?

E.g. which code number for "Registered", "Attended", "On waitlist", "Cancelled", etc?

I'm sure this info must exist but I can't find it in the documentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to know it is goin to Admin -> CiviEvent -> Participant Status

You will see all the Participant Status. Put the mouse over the "Edit" but dont click it. And you will see the url you will be redirected if you click it. This utl is like: "http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/participant_status?action=update&id=2&reset=1"

The id you are looking for is the id variable, which in the case I show you above is 2. (id=2)

I hope this is what you need!

EDIT: No need for the link. Just int the page of Participant Status you can see it in the column:  "Name (Status ID)"

Comment: Thanks. For ease of reference for anyone else with this question:

**1** Registered,
**2** Attended,
**3** No-show,
**4** Cancelled,
**5** Pending (pay later),
**6** Pending (incomplete transaction),
**7** On waitlist,
**8** Awaiting approval,
**9** Pending from waitlist,
**10** Pending from approval,
**11** Rejected,
**12** Expired,
**13** Pending in cart,
**14** Partially paid,
**15** Pending refund,
**16** Transferred